# How do I collapse elements in a Report Table?

Tags: reporting-services

I have an SSRS report where I need to collapse data into a summary column like so:
+Program
-Program2
  Program2DataElement1 | Program2DataElement2 | etc.

How does one doe this?  I see it in other reports, but can't for the life of me find the area to set it up.  When I put in a group, I get something like this on all records: 
Program
  ProgramDataElement | ProgramDataElement | ...

What am I mising?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe these are the steps:

1. Edit group
2. Click on Visibility Tab
3. For Initial Visibility, select the "hidden" radio button.

Comment: This collapses the group, but how do I get the Plus and minus signs? The group loads collapsed, but I can't expand it.

Comment: did you set the "Visibility can be toggled by another report item" to the parent "report item"?

Comment: I tried, but it didn't show up in the drop-box.  I only saw many textboxes listed there.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

For SSRS 2008 - We have:

1. Select Group Properties for Program2DataElement at Row Groups
2. Select option Visibility
3. When the report is initially run: **Hide**
4. Check Display can be toggled by this report item: **Program2**